# How do I find the intersection of a vector and the side of a triangle?

Tags: geometry

I have a triangle with given vertices ABC. Given a vector that starts from A and intersects side BC, how can I find the point of intersection, p?

See diagram:

[image: Diagram]

Comment: We have [Math.SE] for math questions (for future reference).

Answer (score 0):

Parametrize the line BC as `B+s(C-B)` with `s` going from `0` to `1`. Do the same for the vector, i.e. as `A + t(D-A)`, where D is any point along the vector, and the range of `t` is not limited.

Now denote the coordinates of the points as A.x, A.y and so on. You have to solve the equations

`A.x + t(D.x - A.x) == B.x + s(C.x - B.x)`

`A.y + t(D.y - A.y) == B.y + s(C.y - B.y)`

to determine `s` and `t`. Then `p = B+s(C-B)` where `s` is the solution of the equation. There might be an easier solution for triangles, but this should work!

Comment: I'm not very experienced with parametric equations, how would I solve the equations to determine s and t? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: You bring the first equation into the form `s==...` and then insert that result into the second equation. From there you determine t. Maybe the following helps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations